# affine morphism 

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let G, X and Y are algebraic schemes over k.(k:field)
Assume that G is affine, and that the action is proper. Then f:X -> Y is affine.
This is the Proposition0.7 in 'GIT(mumford & Fogarty)'
I don't understand the part of the proof of this Prop.

g: G×Y -> X is a proper morphism. 
P_2: G×Y -> Y is the second projection and affine morphism.
and f·g=p_2.
The author says "by Chevalley's Theorem(EGA 2, Theorem 6.7.1), f is affine".
I can't draw it.
Please, help me...

(*Chevalley's Thm:
X: affine scheme, Y: noetherian pre-scheme, f: x -> Y is a finite surjective morphism
Then Y is also affine.)

Comment: Which action of $G$ on what?

Comment: This is not well-posed in my opinion. Do you mean that $G$ is to be an affine group scheme and that furthermore $G$ acts on $X$ and that $Y$ is the quotient of $X$ modulo $G$? Maybe you should first edit the question in order to make it precise.

Answer (score 1):

$g$ is also affine (EGA II, 1.6.1 (v)), hence finite (EGA III, 4.4.2).